# Merge two data frames by a max number condition in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, dt

Cheers, I have a data frame df1 with the Major City with max visitors in 2011.

```
df1:
Country      City             Visitors_2011
UK           London           100000
USA          Washington D.C   200000
USA          New York         100000
France       Paris            100000
```

The other data frame df2 consists of top visited cities in the country for 2012:

```
df2:
Country      City               Visitors_2012
USA          Washington D.C     200000
USA          New York           100000
USA          Las Angeles        100000
UK           London             100000
UK           Manchester         100000
France       Paris              100000
France       Nice               100000
```

The Output I would need is:
Logic: To obtain df3, merge df1 and df2 by Country and City and if you can't find city in df1 then add that volume to biggest city in df1.
Example: Los Angeles visitor count here is added to Washington D.C because Los Angeles is not present in df1 and Washington D.C has more visitors(2012) than New York.

```
df3:
Country      City             Visitors_2011    Visitors_2012
UK           London           100000           200000
USA          Washington D.C   200000           300000
USA          New York         100000           100000
France       Paris            100000           200000
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Lookup `?match` and try `df3 <- df1;
df3$Visitors_2012 <- df2$Visitors_2012[match(df1$City, df2$City)];`

Comment: @Maurits this won't merge cities that are not in df1 as specified by the question.

Comment: @SairamReddy, you seem to be asking many very similar questions. Perhaps try concentrate on one at a time. It could be that the tools to solve one will also solve the other. It would help also to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), as well as show us what you have tried.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee yes you're right. Sloppy reading on my part. Ignore my comment.

Comment: I actually did spend some time on your previous question and managed to solve it but by the time I went to post my answer the question was gone.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I just wanted to change the question so that it's better understandable.

Comment: @Sotos Apologies for taking off the question. Just wanted to make better understandable. Nevertheless can you direct me to the approach?

Comment: Well I am not at a computer anymore but I will post an answer as soon as I get home if it is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
max.cities <- df1 %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(City = City[which.max(Visitors_2011)])
result <- df2 %>% mutate(City=ifelse(City %in% df1$City, City,
                                     max.cities$City[match(Country, max.cities$Country)])) %>%
                  group_by(Country,City) %>%
                  summarise(Visitors_2012=sum(Visitors_2012)) %>% 
                  left_join(df1,., by=c("Country", "City"))
```

Notes:

1. First, compute the `City` that has the `max` visitors `group_by` `Country` in `df1` and set that to a separate data frame `max.cities`.
2. `mutate` the `City` column in `df2` so that if the `City` is in `df1`, then the name is unchanged; otherwise, the `City` from `max.cites` that `match`es the `Country` is used.
3. Once the `City` has been suitably modified, `group_by` both `Country` and `City` and sum up the `Visitors_2012`.
4. Finally, `left_join` with `df1` by `c("Country", "City")` to get the final `result`.

The result using your posted data is as expected:

```
print(result)
##  Country           City Visitors_2011 Visitors_2012
##1      UK         London        100000        200000
##2     USA Washington D.C        200000        300000
##3     USA       New York        100000        100000
##4  France          Paris        100000        200000
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume `df1.txt` and `df2.txt` contain your space-delimited dataframes.

Here is a solution in base R:

```
df1 <- read.table("df1.txt", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F);
df2 <- read.table("df2.txt", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F);

# Merge with all = TRUE, see ?merge 
df <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE);

# Deal with missing values
tmp <- lapply(split(df, df$Country), function(x) {
    # Make sure NA's are at the bottom
    x <- x[order(x$Visitors_2011), ];
    # Select first max Visitors_2012 entry
    idx <- which.max(x$Visitors_2012);
    # Add any NA's to max entry
    x$Visitors_2012[idx] <- x$Visitors_2012[idx] + sum(x$Visitors_2012[is.na(x$Visitors_2011)]);
    # Return dataframe
    return(x[!is.na(x$Visitors_2011), ])});
# Bind list entries into dataframe
df <- do.call(rbind, tmp);

print(df);
       Country           City Visitors_2011 Visitors_2012
France  France          Paris        100000        200000
UK          UK         London        100000        200000
USA.6      USA       New_York        100000        100000
USA.7      USA Washington_D.C        200000        300000
```